# An operation is already in progress error while accessing DB from middleware

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, async-await, .net-core, npgsql

Hello,

I have an ASP.NET Core app with EF Core running on postgresql db server. I ran into this problem:

When I access DB from a controller, everything works fine.
But when I try to access DB from a middleware, an exception occurs (both under higher request load):

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: An operation is already in progress.
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReaderInternalAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
...
```

Sample code:

---

DB configuration

```cs
private void ConfigureDatabase(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigObject.Value.DbContextSettings.ConnectionString;
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opts => opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
}
```

DbContext

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, Guid>
  {

        ...

        public DbSet<SomeItem> SomeItems { get; set; }

        ...
  }
```

The middleware

```cs
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)  
        {
                var test = await _context.SomeItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

An controller

```cs
public async Task<SomeItem> GetStuff()  
        {
                return await _context.SomeItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

---

My question is - Why is the controller able to serve many async concurrent request and the middleware not? And how can I get it work too? I'm little bit lost in asynchronicity and ASP.NET anatomy right now.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use constructor injection in middleware, if dependency lifetime is scoped it causes [captive dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). You used `ApplicationDbContext` and it is scoped. So the problem probably occurs from this reason. To avoid, you can pass dependency into `Invoke` method as a parameter:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ApplicationDbContext _context)  
    {
         var test = await _context.SomeItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the error but both methods aren't the same.  middleware doesn't have a return type and controller does 'SomeItem'.  Also, just return the Async method right away and drop the asnyc await from the Task.

> public async Task GetStuff()
>           {
>                   return await _context.SomeItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
>           }

```
public Task<SomeItem> GetStuff()  
{
    return _context.SomeItems.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```